# PayPal iOS simulator app accepts invalid passwords

Tags: ios, paypal, sdk, passwords

I am working on integrating the PayPal SDK into an iOS app.  I created a sandbox account, got a client id, etc...  The didCompletePayment method gets successfully called, and everything appears to look good with the results that I output via the description method on the returned object.  However, when I went to the Developer Portal on PayPal to look for a recent Notification of the Sandbox transaction, it wasn't there.  My primary question is...  why would everything appear to be successful, but it not show up in the Developer portal with a notification of the payment?  (On a side-note, I made a similar app for Android, and it does show up there.)  Is there something I can do to track down what might be wrong?  One detail I noticed in the description data that was outputted to the console, is a response.id being "pay-nonetworkpayidexample123".  Would that have anything to do with this?

In addition, I noticed that the when Logging in to PayPal in my app to make the sandbox payment, it accepts ANY password.  That seems like a problem.  Would that have something to do with this as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using the no-network preconnect. See if you find this call:

```
[PayPalMobile preconnectWithEnvironment:PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork];
```

And change for this:

```
[PayPalMobile preconnectWithEnvironment:PayPalEnvironmentSandbox];
```

Comment: That was it!  Somehow I glossed over that variable and figured initially it would be either Production or not.  There's apparently the 3rd option that was initially set from the example I pulled from.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, you will need to change from Sandbox to Production before releasing the App.